# Properly loading classes from a jar's byte array

Tags: java, jar, dynamic-class-loaders

**I know there are questions that address the same problem, trust me I've been through them but none of those contained an answer for my problem.** I want to load a class from a byte array and validate its contents. I have the byte[] for the class but I can't get my custom classloader to actually load it.
For simplicity I created the following function to read the jar file bytes:

```
final String dotJar = "path/to/jar/file";
File file = new File(dotJar);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] contents = new byte[(int) file.length()];
fis.read(contents, 0, contents.length);
InputStream fStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(contents);
```

Quite simple as it is. From here on I retrieve the class file from this stream using the following code:

```
JarInputStream jis = new JarInputStream(fStream);
JarEntry entry;
do {
    entry = jis.getNextJarEntry();
    if (entry == null) {
        break;
    }

    if ("<packagename>/<classname>.class".equals(entry.getName())) {
        byte[] pContents = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
        jis.read(pContents, 0, pContents.length);
        ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        MyClassLoader mcl = new MyClassLoader(cl, pContents);
        Class<?> pConnector = mcl.loadClass("<packagename>.<classname>");
        if (pConnector == null) {
            System.out.println("Failed.");
            break;
        }
        Method[] declaredMethods = pConnector.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method _m : declaredMethods) {
            System.out.println(_m.getName());
        }
    }
} while (true);
```

The structure looks like this inside the jar file:

```
<packagename>
 <classname>$1.class
 <classname>.class
```

If I use the `<classname>$1.class` and pass `<packagename>.<classname>$1` for the loadClass method I get the only method that is defined in that class which is run. When I try to use the actual class that I want to load I get various Exceptions. I'll provide all details with the source of my ClassLoader "implementation".

```
private class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private byte[] classContents;

    public MyClassLoader(ClassLoader parent, final byte[] cls) {
        super(parent);

        classContents = new byte[cls.length];
        classContents = Arrays.copyOf(cls, cls.length);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws NoClassDefFoundError {
        Class<?> cls;

        try {
            cls = super.findSystemClass(name);
        } catch (final ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            cls = defineClass(name, classContents, 0, classContents.length);
        }

        resolveClass(cls);

        return cls;
    }
}
```

If I leave MyClassLoader as it is I'm getting the following StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: <packagename>/<classname>$1 (wrong name: <packagename>/<classname>)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at poolexecutor.ValidationExample$MyClassLoader.loadClass(ValidationExample.java:35)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1962)
    at poolexecutor.ValidationExample.main(ValidationExample.java:70)
Java Result: 1
```

If I remove the try block and leave only the loadClass within the catch block alone:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:659)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:758)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at poolexecutor.ValidationExample$MyClassLoader.loadClass(ValidationExample.java:35)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at poolexecutor.ValidationExample$MyClassLoader.loadClass(ValidationExample.java:35)
    at poolexecutor.ValidationExample.main(ValidationExample.java:65)
Java Result: 1
```

To solve this problem I remove the name attribute from the defineClass call which results yet another Exception with the following StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCircularityError: <packagename>/<classname>
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at poolexecutor.ValidationExample$MyClassLoader.loadClass(ValidationExample.java:35)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at poolexecutor.ValidationExample$MyClassLoader.loadClass(ValidationExample.java:35)
    at poolexecutor.ValidationExample.main(ValidationExample.java:65)
Java Result: 1
```

There are no ClassCircularityError-s. My Class uses other classes but those classes are not using `<classname>` in any way. There are no imports from those classes to `<packagename>.<classname>`. Here's a hierarchy how my jar's classes are organized:

```
Source Packages
  1) PooledTCPConnector.java (Uses 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) 
pooledtcpconnector.utilities
  2) BackgroundWorker.java (Uses: 8)
  3) ConnectionCache.java (Uses: -)
  4) HTTPResponse.java (Uses: -)
  5) ILogger.java (Interface)
pooledtcpconnector.wrappers
  6) HTTPHeadersWrapper.java (Uses: 7, 8)
  7) RequestHeaders.java (Uses: -)
  8) ResponseHeaders.java (Uses: -)
```

I honestly don't see any CircularReferences in here in any way. I could debug my application until defineClass where the byte[] within MyClassLoader contains the correct bytes which are exactly the ones within the class file in my jar. So let's assume that the byte[] is correct but I still can't get defineClass to work.

What am I doing wrong?

@Edit:
By slightly modifying MyClassLoader according to the following:

```
private static class StreamLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private byte[] classContents;

    public StreamLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    public void setClass(final byte[] cls) {
        classContents = new byte[cls.length];
        classContents = Arrays.copyOf(cls, cls.length);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws NoClassDefFoundError {
        Class<?> cls;

        try {
            cls = super.findSystemClass(name);
        } catch (final ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            cls = defineClass(name, classContents, 0, classContents.length);
        }

        resolveClass(cls);

        return cls;
    }
}
```

Loading the classname$1.class first then classname.class fixes all problems. Now my only question would be Why? Why do I need to load both classname$1.class and classname.clss in order to be able to use the Class returned by the loadClass method? I know that classname$1.class contains nested classes, but the truth is, I have no nested classes, not even anonymous ones. Here's how it looks:

```
StreamLoader mcl = new StreamLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
mcl.setClass(get0);
Class<?> cls0 = mcl.loadClass("pooledtcpconnector.PooledTCPConnector$1");
mcl.setClass(get1);
Class<?> cls1 = mcl.loadClass("pooledtcpconnector.PooledTCPConnector");
PrintDeclaredMethods(cls0);
PrintDeclaredMethods(cls1);
```

PrintDeclaredMethod is rather simple. Prints the Class's CanonicalName and under it its declared Method names slightly indented. Here's the output:

```
null
    run
pooledtcpconnector.PooledTCPConnector
    openConnection
    setRequestHeaders
    SendSynchronousRequest
    Initialize
    QueryWebservice
```

this is indeed corrent as PooledTCPConnector has those exact functions declared in it, and I believe the null is the $1.class file which contains that run function. If I leave out one of the currently loaded classes I get a NoClassDefFoundError. My question would be, Why?

Thanks!
 - Joey

Comment: The use of `<package>` and `<classname>` is utterly confusing. - Make sure to quote strings containing `<` in text blocks. (Edited)